# PyOpenSSL - where are all the encryption functions?

Tags: openssl, python

In answering [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/126151/61443), I'm looking at [the docs for PyOpenSSL](http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html) - a python wrapper for OpenSSL.

It's got signatures and certificate stuff, but where's all the encryption stuff? Am I missing something, or is this a massively under-featured port of OpenSSL?

What's the standard way to do crypto in python if the openssl port is so lacking?

Answer (score 1):

Self-answer:

It seems that Python's [Cryptography package](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) is what I was looking for; it provides all the cryptographic primitives that I would have expected to find in OpenSSL.

Comment: The link seems dead(

Comment: @AndrePolykanine Yup, dead or just down, but Googling "python cryptography package" brings up lots of stuff.